# What is the best solution to use one icon with differents colors in android?

Tags: android, svg, icons, svg-android

I've tried to use icons with svg format with svg-android but it doesn't work. 
I've create a drawable from a the svg file and use it for a ImageView ImageResource but the image is invisible.
So How can i do that with svg-android? or with a different way?

Here an [exemple for icons that i want to use](http://linea.io/):

I want to use it with SVG format because i want to use the same icon with another color.

Here my XML file:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home_desc_butt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"

            />
```

Here My onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_campaign_details, container, false);
    home_desc_butt = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_desc_butt);
    SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(rootView.getResources(), R.raw.icon_house_alt);
    Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
     home_desc_butt.setImageDrawable(drawable);

}
```

Comment: How does the icon look?

Comment: It's a linear icon, but it not shown in my layout

Comment: could you post the icon?

Comment: I added a link containing the icons i want to use

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use SVG for your icons then there are a few libraries out there which might help:

Google has a library AndroidSVG for this which you can use : https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/wiki/Tutorial

However it would recommend cutting these assets in photoshop.

Svgs can be quite slow and might not look great on devices with higher pixel densities..

Comment: Yes i know.. is that library that i use..
I'm not using svg to resize my icons, but to color my icons. i have a pack of black icons that i want to use it with white and blue colors, it  will be a long work to color all my app icons with photoshop

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution to colorize my icons without using svg-android library:

```
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.RED, Color.RED);
    home_desc_butt.setColorFilter(filter);
```

That works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you Michael Mullany for your help :)